# How do i get text from a dynamic element with selenium?

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, browser-automation

So this is my xpath :

```
.//*[@id='highcharts-m6xwk29-6']/svg/rect[1]
```

Every time you refresh or access the page , this part `"m6xwk29-6"` changes with random characters and numbers . I have tried with `contains` but it does not work at all . This is the `CssSelector` :

```
#highcharts-efwz4kr-2 > svg > text:nth-child(23)
```

I just wanna get the text from this element . The `html` for this element is the following :

```
<text x="635" text-anchor="end" class="highcharts-plot-line-label " transform="translate(0,0)" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#dedede;fill:#dedede;" y="86" visibility="visible">1.07162</text>
```

The text that i wanna get is a value (in this case `1.07162`) from a graph that updates every second (or less) .

Comment: You should provide html source so someone could help you, not just html of your text element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath`:

```
'//*[starts-with(@id, "highcharts-")]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="text"]'
```

Comment: This returns an empty string if I use it like that-         String strikeChart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[starts-with(@id, 'highcharts-')]/*[name()=\"svg\"]/*[name()=\"rect\"])[2]")).getText(); and null if a i use the method getAttribute("text")  (or value)

Comment: Could you provide with little more piece of `HTML` for `svg` element to allow me to see the whole picture?

Comment: <svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="690" height="520" viewBox="0 0 690 520"> .... This is the parent : <div id="highcharts-efwz4kr-2" class="highcharts-container " style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 690px; height: 520px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">..

Comment: No, I mean with child elements. Update your question with complete `HTML` of `<svg><rect>...</rect></svg>` or share target `URL` if it's not confidential info

Comment: Hmm , the HTML code with child elements is a little bit long because it has many elements but i'll try though.

Comment: You can leave just required child elements to make it shorter

Comment: <g class="highcharts-plot-lines-100"><path fill="none" stroke="#dedede" stroke-width="1" d="M 10 179.5 L 634 179.5"></path></g><text x="624" text-anchor="end" class="highcharts-plot-line-label " transform="translate(0,0)" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#dedede;fill:#dedede;" y="176" visibility="visible">1.07056</text>